# Dynamic sql query using migrations

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, migration

I have a list of string. I want to update a column in the table dependency in the Id value.

This is my c# code:

```
public partial class final : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < CustomerDesType.Types.Length; i++)
        {
            string curText = CustomerDesType.Types[i];
            string query = "UPDATE MembershipTypes " +
                            "SET Desc= " + curText + 
                            " WHERE Id = " + (i + 1);
            Sql(query);
        }
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

But I cannot run `update-database`, I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'

I want to match the Id column to the CustomerDesType.Types[i+1].

Comment: Do not use string concat for queries.  Use parameters.

Comment: Can u give me an example?

Comment: I don't know what database you're using, but see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types).

Comment: @Zer0 It will be good if you read the context of the question before providing general advices. Can you show how one can parameterize [DbMigration.Sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.sql?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) method?

Comment: @ofekRozenkrantz You have to enclose string literals with `'`, e.g. `"SET Desc= '" + curText + "'" +`

Comment: @IvanStoev You should **never** use string concatenation for SQL parameters.  Period.  The context is irrelevant.  As for answering this question I have no idea how this code is producing an alias with `as`.  Finally, the linked documentation (and tons of questions on here) show you how to use parameters.  Some people hate type safety and love SQL injection attacks I suppose.

Comment: @Zer0 so if i will store the array in new table by this form:
Id is the key
Message is the string value, 
and use this table for the query instead of the array. Is it good idea?

Comment: @Zer0 The point is that you **cannot** use parameters in this context. Linked documentation (and tons of questions on here) are **not applicable**, thus *useless*.

Comment: @IvanStoev Sure you can.  Refactor the `Sql` method to accept a _command_ not a _string_.  Done.

Comment: @IvanStoev Fine, I'll post an answer how to do this the right way (**not** using string concat).  Give me a few I'm in the middle of something.

Comment: @IvanStoev can i use the third parameter of Sql method for the parameter?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=entity-framework-6.2.0#overloads

Comment: @ofekRozenkrantz The docs say *"Additional arguments that may be processed by providers. Use anonymous type syntax to specify arguments e.g. 'new { SampleArgument = "MyValue" }'."* Doesn't sound like a way to pass `DbParameter`s, right? `Sql` method cannot use parameters, period. Use the *correct* string concatenation and you are done.

Comment: I don't believe that third argument works that way.  This is [worth a read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql).  Make note of the giant yellow warning box.  I will come back to this question later and post an answer when I get the time to code and test this myself.

Comment: @Zer0 Again you are linking to a wrong place - now the EF **Core** raw sql queries, while the question is about EF6  **Migration**. And btw, EF Core **migrations** have similar [`Sql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.sql?view=efcore-3.1) method with the exact same semantics and lack of parameter support. Shortly, you **can't** post an answer to this question using parameters because no such capability exists in OP context.

Comment: Ok thank you IvanStoev I am using your solution and its work. 
Thank you too Zer0. But i wonder what is the correct way to do this. I could create a table that contains the strings and id for each string. Then use this table to do the query and by this way i do not use c# array. What is the correct way?

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm not going to argue.  I understand EF of all variations.  If you feel that strongly, post an answer using string concat for parameters and call it day.  As for OP, see the various other methods on `DbMigration` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration?view=entity-framework-6.2.0).